# WebView file and camera Feld send me to home page of the web app

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, odoo, ios13

I was trying to put my web app in to `WebView`
but I think something is missing because

when I use html file input `<input type="file" class="o_input_file" name="ufile">`

the iOS photo liberty picker appears and am send the the original/first page in the web app

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://test.com")!) )
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("home"))
    }
    
    
    
}




struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable{
    let request: URLRequest
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I tried to solve the problem my self and found [this apple form](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/22726)

So I added those privacy settings according to the suggestions:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires to access your photo library to upload photo on forms</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires to access your photo library to upload existing photos to forms</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires to access your Microphone to acees camera to upload files to form </string>
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires to access your Media library to upload photo on forms</string>
```

But this did not solve my problem
and then I saw this but don't know where to put it

```
override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)
{
    if self.presentedViewController != nil {
        super.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

[Gif of the screen](https://netstech-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/moaz_netstream-me_com/EYq-ZNh-sGtJtvEarEo5iT4BZsfkDEVm42mKg_CZgQvkYA?e=49yVc6)

Comment: "because when I use file input filed the selection menu shows"  I suppose you are saying that the selection menu appears when you use a file input field.  If so, what is the file input field and what is the selection menu?

Comment: @ElTomato I added a GIF of the Screen 
HTML  file input field `<input type="file" class="o_input_file" name="ufile">` 
selection menu iOS photo library or camera

Comment: I read "This link has been removed."

Comment: @ElTomato sorry now is working

Comment: it works in safari browser but not in the WebView @ElTomato

Comment: @ElTomato can you till me what is the problem

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand your question.  I doubt I can help you.